# How to PHP client-side check if a url of a web site is valid?

Tags: php, validation, url, client-side

I've searched in SO questions but found solutions are based on calling `ping` command executed from using `system` PHP function.

My web host server doesn't allow me to do that. What should I do?

### Note

I need to check from the client/web-browser side.

Comment: What do you mean by a client side check of a Url?

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't load a external webpage with ajax to check if the page responds, you can do the following:

- First check if the url string is even valid using regexp:

javascript:

**Edited to be A LOT more forgiving. Since javascript doesn't support unicode character matching without any third party libraries this was the approach I chose:**

```
function Validate(url){ 
    var pattern = /(https?:\/\/)?.+\.[a-z]{2,4}/i 
    return pattern.test(url); 
} 

alert(Validate("http://abcü好le2.com/?query=test&test=1")); //true
alert(Validate("https://hurmårdu.se/blog/?test=1")); //true
alert(Validate("abcü好le2.com/?query=test&test=1")); //true
alert(Validate("hurmårduse/blog/?test=1")); //false
alert(Validate("hurmårduse")); //false
```

Note: To make this function even better we can add support to add http:// at the start of the string if it doesn't contain it. Also if you are interested in unicode regexp: http://xregexp.com/plugins/

- If yes, then make an ajax request to your backend
- The backend takes the url sent with the ajax request and loads the url with either the solution Flave gave you or, and returns whether the url is responsive or not:

php:

```
$url = $_POST["url"];
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);       
curl_close($ch);
if(strlen($output)){
    return json_encode(array("is_valid" => true, "value" => $url));
}else{
    return json_encode(array("is_valid" => false, "value" => $url));
}
```

Note: Code needs sanitation of data sent from ajax request.

Comment: Regular expressions are too error-prone for validating URLs. For example your pattern doesn't support umlauts. I discourage from using a regular expression. Besides that, you wouldn't know if that URL is in use.

Comment: Well, we are not relying on the regexp here, it's just means to sort out invalid urls instead of spending resources to actually load the url. Also we can adapt the regexp to be more forgiving so we just sort out the urls which have major errors in them.

Answer (score 0):

Does your host allow using curl or socket() functions? Or perhaps doing remote includes with the fopen command? Thats probably a much better alternative than using the system("ping") command.

Answer (score 0):

a simple check in php would be

```
if(strlen(file_get_contents('http://google.com')){ // do something }
```

client-side could be tricky, because most browsers doesnt allow cross-side-scripting

alternatively you could use php-curl if installed.

Answer (score 0):

The function `gethostbyname` and `checkdnsrr` (this one is not implemented on Windows) will check if a given host name correspond to a DNS record (so essentially if a given host name is public). It should be more fast then `file_get_contents` and `curl` ;-)